# Controlar se um tkinter.Text está vazio

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou a tentar criar um simples bloco de notas, mas tenho um pequeno problema:
quando tento ver se o texto dum objecto `Text` está ou não vazio:

```
if text_area.get(0.0, tkinter.END) != "":
    print("Text não vazio") # é sempre executado
```

Quando eu tento usar a função `len` para controlar a comprimento do texto, retorna 1.

Qual é afinal este caracter predefinido? A minha solução seria controlar o comprimento do texto com 1 (ou talvez melhor, se o comprimento é maior que 1), e se retorna True, quer dizer que está "vazio".

Já agora, porquê que o *Python*, ou melhor a livraria `tkinter` fornece um indicador de final de texto, ou seja `tkinter.END`, e não de inicio? Porquè que tenho que meter **0.0** (e não `tkinter.START`)?

(Em comparação por exemplo a linguagem Java, e em particular a sua livraria Swing, a livraria tkinter é mesmo pouco intuitiva, mesmo franquinha sinceramente)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
if text_area.get(1.0, tkinter.END) != "":
    print("Text não vazio")
```

`1.0` Significa linha *1*, coluna *0*, as linhas são indexadas a partir de *1* e colunas são indexados em *0*.

No seguinte link([**`Text widget indices`**](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-index.html)) descreve algumas formas para se trabalhar com índices em *widgets* utilizando o *TKinter*.

Comment: Sem dúvida o *TKinter* é um excelente módulo, porém existem outros muito bons como o Gtk, Qt. [**Aqui**](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui.html#id1) tem algo sobre. Sobre o `len` eu ainda não sei como lhe ajudar.